# Implement shutdown screen

Tags: shutdown, arm64, embedded-system

Is it possible to implement a “shutdown screen” like the good old Windows 95 “It is now safe to turn off your computer” screen? I’m thinking of an executable that displays a shutdown page fullscreen and halts or hangs the processor at the end of the shutdown process, so the user has to power the unit off physically. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 (not Core) on an ARM64 embedded system (based on Nvidia Jetson AGX Xavier) and for some reason, the regular shutdown process just restarts the system. It's a known issue on the hardware I'm using, and I need to find a workaround.

Comment: To clarify, are you using  Ubuntu 18.04, or Ubuntu Core 18? You can [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1411279/edit) to add this info. But generally, the short answer is yes. Ubuntu is open-source, so it is possible. _How_ may depend on your version of Ubuntu, so if you add that, we may be able to help. Thanks!

Comment: @cocomac good point. I added the details of the OS version.